# Конвертировал mp3 в hex, как конвертировать hex в mp3 обратно?

Tags: python, файлы, hex

Я нашел вопрос, где человек хотел конвертировать файл в hex [(вот ссылка)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964245/convert-file-to-hex-string-python), что и пригодилось мне. Но такой вот вопрос: а как конвертировать обратно, если я конвертировал mp3 в hex и теперь надо наоборот?

Comment: Вы какую задачу всё-таки изначально решаете? Мне кажется, вы куда-то не туда всё-таки копаете.

Comment: ну, я хочу конвертировать в текст и наоборот, это пока что моя начальная задача. А вот сжать это второстепенное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

немного поискав в самом туториале библеотеки, я нашел интересную команду `unhexlify`.

Вот сам код:

```py
import binascii
filename = 'x.mp3'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
    hexed = binascii.hexlify(content)

unhexed = binascii.unhexlify(hexed)
a = open("output.mp3","wb")
a.write(unhexed)
```